# Drupal6: Every node view of a certain type leads to 404 error

Tags: php, drupal-6, view, cck

For some reason, trying to view any node of a certain content type leads to a 404 error. When viewed in a View table, they display just fine. What could be happening?

Viewing the database with phpMyAdmin shows the data just fine.

The problematic node type was created with CCK.

Comment: This is not programming related.  Sounds much more like a server administration/configuration issue.  Recommend moving to serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Drupal log show 'page not found' errors when you attempt to access those URLs? If it doesn't, the requests are never making it to Drupal, which would likely indicate you've got a misconfigured `.htaccess` file.

Comment: it's not the .htaccess file - I have another version of this project that lacks this bug, and the .htaccess files between those two are identical. what else?

Comment: Do these access attempts show up in the Drupal log as they should?

Comment: They do not show up in the "top page not found errors", if that's what you mean. where else would I look?

Comment: You should see individually logged errors at http://example.com/admin/reports/dblog ('Recent log entries'). If you access one of those URLs and no error shows up in the dblog, Drupal is never getting to handle the request.